# how to get children of node in jqGrid treegrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to get the children of the selected node in jqGrid but it seems it is not possible.

I have this in onSelectRow event.

```
            onSelectRow: function (rowid, status, e) {
                var row = $(this).getRowData(rowid)
                var children = $(this).getNodeChildren(row);
                //alert(JSON.stringify(children));
                alert(JSON.stringify(row));
            }
```

"children" variable always contains children of root node, not of the selected one. Selected node is correctly displayed in the alert.

Comment: Can you create a quick demo? jsfiddle/snippet/codepen

Comment: You can check here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/yNw3C/15290/. getNodeChildren always return the child of the root node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getLocalRow` instead of `getRowData`. The corresponding fixed code could look like the following

```
onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
    var $self = $(this),
        row = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        children = $self.jqGrid("getNodeChildren", row);

    alert(JSON.stringify(children));
}
```

Comment: Thanks... it worked... however, I have another problem now. I need to get underlying row object for children. I have tried, for example, var node = $(this).getRowData(children[0]._id_);, but it always returns the row, not the underying object. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @jstuardo: You are welcome! I can repeat, you should use `getLocalRow` instead of `getRowData` to get the data. The method `getLocalRow` returns **all** information about the row inclusive TreeGrid specific properties `parent`, `level` and so on. The method `getRowData` returns only the information, which are placed in the DOM of the row. Moreover, please write always which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: no.... neither getLocalRow nor getRowData return the underlying row object.. apparently it is getting only columns from the model, which is different from loadComplete event. In loadComplete event, the function parameter contains the full JSON object, so when getting the "rows" property, it returns a collection of objects with all JSON properties. I wanted to achieve the same but in onSelectRow. It seems it is not possible to get underlying object in that event, so I will try to add other properties to the model in a hidden state and see if getLocalRow can get it.

Comment: @jstuardo: Sorry, but I can't follow you. You can see that `row = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid)` do works  in the above answer. Every **other** callback function, like `loadComplete`, for example, has **his own parameters** (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) for example), which are related to the goal of the callback function. I'm not sure what you want to implement inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: I want to implement inside onSelectRow.... I mentioned loadComplete only as an example of what I needed, but never mind. I have done what i told you. I have added the object missing properties to the model and in hidden state. That way, when getting node children, I could access the properties correctly.

Comment: @jstuardo: It's better if you would post some code or at least write which version and which fork of jqGrid you use. You wrote "I have added the object missing properties to the model and in hidden state." for example. I suppose that you mean that you added columns in `colModel` with the property `hidden: true`. The properties of the data will be not only accessible via `getLocalRow`, but *be saved in DOM of HTML table*, which makes the page more slowly. It could be a problem with large number of items.

Comment: @jstuardo: Free jqGrid allows to use `additionalProperties` instead of `colModel`. The properties will be just saved locally as JavaScript data, but `additionalProperties` will be not placed on DOM. I can explain that better, but it has no sense if you use *another fork* of jqGrid or an old version, which has no such possibility.

Comment: you are right with respect on what I did. I notice you know jqGrid. Of course, if a person knows jqGrid, he could understand with a few words... these are few data so performance is not a problem. Rather than implementing a more sophisticated solution, I prefered to use colModel, which I have at hand.By the way, version is jqGrid 4.6.0. Cheers.